# How to access in module - OpenERP web/http.py methods 

Tags: odoo

In openerp 6.1 windows I tried to capture public IP address when people sign-in and sign-out from the HR module. So, in the hr_attendance module I've added ip_address field. Client Public IP address available in the web\common\http.py  environ['REMOTE_ADDR']

```
from osv import fields, osv
from web.common.http import Root

class hr_attendance(osv.osv):

  def _get_ipaddress(self, cr, uid, context=None):
    ip = None
    try:
       # environ['REMOTE_ADDR'] how to get 
    except Exception, e:
      pass
    return ip

_inherit = "hr.attendance"
_columns = {
       'ip_address' : fields.char('IP Address', readonly=True, size=64)
        }

_defaults = {
        'ip_address': _get_ipaddress,
    }
```

hr_attendance()

How can I get the client IP address or environ['REMOTE_ADDR"] in the default method? Which class and method do I need to override in hr_attendance module?

In my doubt is which method need to call in http.py and what are the parameter to pass  get environ['REMOTE_ADDR'] in the HR Module

Comment: Does your code run without errors? I think that `_get_ipaddress` is missing an `ids` parameter after `uid`.

Comment: In my doubts which method need to call and what are the parameters to pass to get environ['Remote_Addr'] from the Hr Module

Answer (score 0):

That looks like it might be difficult to do without changes to the web layer, because the module code doesn't really know anything about the web server layer. The best I could find after a few minutes of digging was a place where you could copy the IP address from the HTTP request to the OpenERP context dictionary. I think if you added this line to the [`WebRequest.init()` method](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~openerp/openerp-web/6.1/view/2479/addons/web/common/http.py#L92), it might do what you need.

```
self.context['remote_addr'] = self.httprequest.remote_addr
```

I think that context will be passed down to the module code where you can read it.